# Fast meringue technique

Tags: baking, cooking-time, meringue

I use the slow method of baking a meringue, [as described here.](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/53638/58098)

I'm aware that there is a fast method, but can't find it online. (Besides, I'd really prefer the human input garnered here!)

Currently, my knowledge would be to mix the meringue as with the slow method, spoon onto baking paper and put in a hot over (possibly 180c?) for 10 minutes.

I have tried that and ended up with [the result shown here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/91026/why-is-my-meringue-soft-moist-and-discoloured) (though not in that particular instance.)

So, does anyone know what the fast meringue method is?

Comment: Are you saying you saw a way to bake a French meringue in 10 minutes? Or are you thinking of other types of meringue, like Italian?

Comment: Honestly, I wasn't thinking of any type of meringue. I'm not familiar enough to tell the difference. I just whip egg white and sugar until stiff, spoon onto baking paper and bake at 140c(!?) for 2 hrs, then leave until the next day.

Comment: That's French meringue @MattW. You can't really rush that, it will be burnt on the outside and raw on the inside. Italian may be the way to go, it's what's used on Baked Alaska. What do you want the meringue for?

Comment: Thanks :) ... General meringue dishes. Pavlova is what I've done so far. I'd like to try lemon meringue pie next.

Comment: @MattW A lemon meringue pie is completely different from a Pavlova. The meringue is not baked at all, just toasted on top. And it can be done with any type of meringue (French, Italian or Swiss). Can you clarify your question? What kind of meringue are you after?

Comment: I'm not after a particular type of meringue. I'm after a fast method of baking.

Comment: But what end result are you after? Cooked hard meringue, chewy meringue, toasted marshmallowy meringue?

Comment: The latter. Hard would be too much for a pie I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some confusion in the comments, I think I have an answer for you. There are three main methods for making a meringue and two main methods of cooking them.

First we have a French meringue, which is what you've made before.

Second, we have Swiss meringue. Here the egg whites and sugar are gently heated over a water bath stirring constantly until the mixture reaches a temperature of 79 degrees Celsius. At this point you transfer the mixture to a mixing bowl and whisk until cooled.

Finally, an Italian meringue is made by whisking a hot simple syrup into the eggs whites.

The different methods of preparation have slightly different outcomes. A French meringue tends to be more fragile before cooking and the end result is lighter. A Swiss or Italian meringue has more volume and tends to be more stable before cooking and have a more marshmallowy/chewy end result.

All these meringue types can be cooked either slowly in the oven as you describe, or toasted. The slow oven cook will produce a meringue that's hard on the outside and either fluffy or chewy on the inside. This is used to make for example Pavlovas or meringue cookies.

For a pie topping, you instead simply pile the meringue on top of the pie and torch it with a blowtorch or (place it in the oven on 'grill') until the top is your desired level of toasted. This takes at most a few minutes. Toasting can be done with any merigue, although Swiss and Italian are preferred, since the egg white has been heated to safe temperatures already. If you toast a French meringue, you are serving mostly raw egg white and need to take appropriate precautions to avoid salmonella.

Comment: Thank you! That's awesome info! I guess my Mum has been toasting Swiss meringue. Certainly, toasting is what I was thinking is actually the "fast" method.